# When defining a lambda function with a variable inside, how to prevent changes in function when I change the variable?

Tags: python

For example: in this code, function changes when the variable changes. I would like to learn how to prevent the change in function behaviour when i change the variable. Is there some way to only get the value of the variable instead of the variable itself? Also are there any sources where I can learn more about problems like this?

```
a = 5
adder = lambda x: x + a
print(adder(5)) # prints 10

a = 50
print(adder(5)) # prints 55
```

Comment: `adder = lambda x, a=a: x + a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like the equivalent function defined by a `def` statement (which is what you should be using, rather than assigning the result of a lambda expression to a name explicitly)

```
def adder(x):
    return x + a
```

the name `a` isn't looked up until the function is *called*.

One way to make a function that specifically computes `x + 5` when `a == 5` at definition time is use a default argument value:

```
def adder(x, a=a):
    return x + a
```

where the left-hand `a` is a new parameter (which isn't intended to be set explicitly), and the right-hand `a` is the value of the `a` in the current scope.

A better idea, though, is to define a closure, so that your function doesn't have a "hidden" parameter that can be abused.

```
# This is where a lambda expression does make sense: you want
# a function, but don't need to give it a name.
def make_adder(a):
    return lambda x: x + a

adder = make_adder(5)
```

`a` in `adder` is still a free variable, but now it refers to a variable in a scope which you don't "outside" access to after `make_adder` returns.

Comment: You can also use a lambda there: `return lambda x: x + a`.

Comment: True; I went overboard in my `def`-not-`lambda` crusade.